# WPF XAML error "Cannot be null parameter name root"

Tags: wpf, xaml

In Visual Studio 2015, I am trying to create a XAML control from an existing base class in my project, but I'm getting the error shown below. What's wrong?

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYAF2.png)

Here's a bit more information:

```
at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique)
   at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters)
   at Render.Core.Models.ModelBase.get_Project()
   at Render.Core.Models.ModelBase.get_Interface()
   at Render.Core.Models.StaticModelBase.get_Interface()
   at Render.Core.RenderControls.RenderHeader..ctor(String title, ContentControl image, Boolean isAdminHome)
   at Render.MainApplication.Views.Shared.ViewBase.CalcSize()
   at Render.MainApplication.Views.Shared.ViewBase.ViewBase_SizeChanged(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireSizeChangedEvents()
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
```

Apparently the problem is related to Ninject. Maybe I need to include some kind of namespace declaration for that?

Comment: I guess your control tried to execute code from an assmebly that doesnt get loaded by the designer. One thing you can do is to debug the designer. Check out this guide: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1040701/How-to-Debug-the-Design-Time-Errors-in-WPF-XAML-Fi

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a try.